# Custom HTML form submission error using admin_post hook

Tags: php, html, wordpress, elementor

I have an HTML form which I have inserted using an HTML Code snippet on elementor. I want to connect it to my wordpress  database. I have looked into wpdb-> insert function but can't get it to work. I am using wp-admin's action hook.

```
<html
  <body>
    <form action="https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post" name="myform">
      <!-- ####################################################### --><br><br>
      <h3>Option1 </h3>
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="1" value="1" /> None of the time &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="1" value="2" /> Rarely&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="1" value="3" /> Some of the Time&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="1" value="4" /> Often&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="a" id="1" value="5" /> All of the Time&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <br /><br />
      <!-- #############################################################-->
      <h3> Option2 </h3>
      <input type="radio" name="p" id="High" value="1" /> None of the time&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="p" id="Medium" value="2" /> Rarely&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="p" id="Low" value="3" /> Some of the Time&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="p" id="Medium" value="4" /> Often&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="p" id="Medium" value="5" /> All of the Time&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
      <!-- ########################################################## -->

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="compass_data">

      <br />
      <br />
      
      <h3><span id="msg"></span></h3>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" onclick="setTimeout(validate, 1500)" />
    <br /><br />

    <script>
/* Some functions here*/
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above JS has a variable that needs to be stored in the database. I am using PHP code snippet plugin to put following PHP code. My question is that where  should I put this PHP code in functions.php or PHP snippet?

```
add_action('admin_post_compass_data','storedata_compass',11);
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_compass_data','storedata_compass',11);

function storedata_compass(){
    if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])){
      global $wpdb;
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $userId = $user->ID;
      $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
        $data = array('Student Id' => $userId, 'First Name' => $user_data -> user_firstname, 'Email' => $user_data -> user_email, 'Group Id' =>             2, 'Intro Selection' => 'DBTEST',   'End Selection' => 'test2');
        $format = array('%d', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s');
    
    $wpdb->insert( 'wpqc_compass', $data, $format);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have now used admin-post.php

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is a bit broken where you set the `$tablename`

```
It should be $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'compass'
```

And not `$tablename = $wpdb-> 'compass';`

But you should get an error when you are trying to run that php code. But you should maybe add it into functions.php.

And you should also not just listen to `$_POST['submit']` because if you have any other form that has a button with the name "submit" it will trigger this php script also.

Comment: I  am now using admin_post action hook to interact with the database but still no use.